# Как найти элементы в каждом DOM, произвести расчет и добавить итог расчета в этот же DOM

Tags: javascript

Есть множество элементов DOM на странице типа:

```
<div class="stats row"><div title="На складе" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-package-6"></span>6
        </div> <div title="К отправке" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-trolley"></span>0
        </div> <div title="Продано" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-shopping-cart-8"></span>4
        </div> <!----> <div title="Просмотров: 112" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-monitor"></span>112
        </div></div>
```

В них отображены данные о количествах продажи и посещаемости.
Нужно найти эти значения, в данном примере 4 продажи и 112 просмотров.
И произвести расчет конверсии по формуле (4/112)*100
и вывести возле количества просмотров.
Подскажите как найти эти два элемента (кол-во продаж и кол-во просмотров) в каждом DOM объекте и вывести результат расчета там же?
Чтобы получилось в итоге как-то так:

```html
<div class="stats row"><div title="На складе" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-package-6"></span>6
        </div> <div title="К отправке" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-trolley"></span>0
        </div> <div title="Продано" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-shopping-cart-8"></span>4
        </div> <!----> <div title="Просмотров: 112" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-monitor"></span>112
        </div> <!----> <div title="Конверсия" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-monitor"></span>3,5%
        </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let shopping = document.querySelectorAll('.stats div[title^="Продано"]');
let views  = document.querySelectorAll('.stats div[title^="Просмотров"]');

for( let i = 0; i < shopping.length; i++ ){
  let a = parseFloat( shopping[i].innerText );
  let b = parseFloat( views[i].innerText );
  let percent = Math.round( 1000 * a / b ) / 10;
  views[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div title="Конверсия" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-monitor"></span>' + percent + '%</div></div>');
}
```

```html
<div class="stats row">
  <div title="На складе" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-package-6"></span>6</div>
  <div title="К отправке" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-trolley"></span>0</div>
  <div title="Продано" class="col-mbs-6"><span class=" flaticon-shopping-cart-8"></span>4</div>
  <div title="Просмотров: 112" class="col-mbs-6"><span class="flaticon-monitor"></span>112</div>
</div>
```

Comment: к сожалению добавить классы я не могу, потому что код нужен для расширения, которое немного улучшает содержание не моего сайта.

Comment: Обновил... должно прокатить. Если они нигде больше не используют схожие title для других целей)

Comment: спасибо! но пока странно на jsfiddle.net отрабатывает норм и здесь, а на сайте не хочет менять. пробовал и в head и в body добавлять скрипт

Comment: @ssdd Пробуйте `let script = document.createElement('script'); script.innerHTML = \`весь JS-код\`; document.body.appendChild(script);` — именно в обратных кавычках ` Или, можно копировать код в консоль и тыкнуть Enter, если это одноразовая штука для удобства - https://i.gyazo.com/f02e2face213b0ebb1e97308ddd7875e.png

Comment: О! Через консоль заработало!
Но через внедрение кода JS пока нет, поищу в чем проблема

Comment: А не подскажите случайно ?
В вашем последнем примере скрипт внедряется перед тегом </body> из консоли - и он отрабатывает отлично.
Я в своем расширении реализовал точно также, на странице скрипт размещается перед тегом </body>, но он почему то не отрабатывает, никак не могу понять в чем  дело

Comment: Так надо после. Во время загрузки страницы, браузер "читает" её сверху вниз. А когда срабатывает скрипт - он запрашивает HTML-элементы, которые еще не догружены, и получается ошибка.

Comment: а не подскажите как правильнее разместить в конец ?